# Customization of sliders not applied

Tags: google-cast-sdk

I am implementing Google Cast SDK 4.4.4 on iOS. I am trying to customize some of the colors. 
Specifically I am trying to change the slider progress colors for the volume and the current time. One view is on the Connection Controller and the other one the small slider at the top of the mini player.

when setting the sliderProgressColor it is just ignored. 
I tried the following calls without any success.

```
castViews.mediaControl.miniController.sliderProgressColor = .red
castViews.mediaControl.expandedController.sliderProgressColor = .red
castViews.mediaControl.expandedController.sliderSecondaryProgressColor = .red
castViews.deviceControl.connectionController.sliderProgressColor = .red
castViews.deviceControl.connectionController.sliderSecondaryProgressColor = .red
castViews.deviceControl.connectionController.toolbar.sliderProgressColor = .red

castViews.deviceControl.sliderProgressColor = .red

castViews.deviceControl.sliderSecondaryProgressColor = .red
```

I would expected that setting the color with the lines

`castViews.mediaControl.miniController.sliderProgressColor = .red`

or

`castViews.deviceControl.sliderProgressColor = .red`

should be sufficient.

Any help on that matter is much appreciated.

Thanks and regards, 
Brian

Comment: At least for the Minicontroller I was able to customize by leveraging the UIAppearance proxy. 
        UIProgressView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [GCKUIMiniMediaControlsViewController.self]).progressTintColor = .red
But for the conneciton controller and the volume control I am stil searching for a solution.

Comment: Hi Brian Nürnberg, any luck ?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue.
It is not working.

castViews.mediaControl.miniController.sliderProgressColor = .yellow